# Page loader for certain elements of the body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loader

I have added to my website this loader

```
$(window).load(function () {
        $("#page-preloader").fadeOut(300);
});
```

which as you can see it fades out after everything of the page is loaded.

I would like to have a loader which fades out right after a class is loaded (i.e. class="myclass")) and not wait for everything to get loaded.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "a class is loaded"?

Comment: for example <div class="myclass">hi i am some content<div>. when this div is loaded the loader should fade out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var load_cs = $('.myclass');

if (load_cs.length) {
    $("#page-preloader").delay(3000).fadeOut(300);
}
```

I did this.. and it is pretty much working as i want. Thanks for the help guys. If anyone has any other advice I will be happy to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.myclass').load(function () {
        $("#page-preloader").fadeOut(300);
});
```

Same format as before, just different selector.

Answer (score 0):

Try using document ready instead of load to see if the effect is what you need

```
$(function() {
    $("#page-preloader").fadeOut(300);
});
```

`load()` will wait for elements that have `url`, `href` and alike attributes.